# How to build javascript files from Haxe using Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, haxe

I have installed Haxe for OS X, and I have installed the Haxe code completion package for Sublime Text. So far this is working - I can type Haxe code and Sublime Text will recognize it.

I have read the Haxe tutorials and documentation, but I can't seem to find anything about compiling the Haxe code to javascript from Sublime Text.

I'm sure it has something to do with the 'build system' in Sublime Text, but I don't see how to get Haxe's tutorial commands into Sublime Text?

From the Haxe website:

Input:

`-cp path:` Adds a class path where .hx source files or packages (sub-directories) can be found.

`-lib library_name:` Adds a Haxelib library.

`-main dot_path:` Sets the main class.

Output:

`-js file_name:` Generates Javascript source code in specified file

`-as3 directory:` Generates Actionscript 3 source code in specified directory.

An example of a build system from the [unofficial SublimeText documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html):

```
{
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Does anybody have any idea how to use this? [The Haxe website](http://haxe.org/documentation/introduction/) seems short on working examples.

Comment: Unless you hard-code the main class name and the libraries, you won't be able to do this with a sublime-build. If you're willing to do that though, you could make two variants for `js` and `as3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `build.hxml` file at the root of your project. Put all the compilation settings in there as you described above and use `CTRL+ENTER` to compile. You can have multiple `hxml` files if you need to compile to multiple targets or chain several compilation procedures in the same build file. Also the file will be used for autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the accepted answer you can also define project specific build systems within your .sublime-project file

```
"build_systems":
[
    {
        "name": "my-build",
        "cmd": ["haxe", "${project_path}/path/to/build.hxml"],
        "working_dir": "${project_path}/path/to/main/class"
    }
]
```

This has the advantage that if you add the working_dir like above you don't need to open your main class file to build the project. And you can easily move the build.hxml to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but i'll answer - here is build system i'm using with ctrl+b shortcut (you can use "haxelib run openfl run ... " for your project.xml, or "haxe build.hxml")

```
    {
        "file_regex": "(\\/.+\\.hx)\\:(\\d+)\\:",
        "name": "Jive",
        "shell_cmd": "haxelib run jive test -debug",
        "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}/jive/tests"
    }
```